# UITableViewCell highlight overlays my custom views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in my app. I add a view to the cell on initialisation.

```
class RestaurantCell: ListTableViewCell {
    public let stripeView: UIView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(stripeView)
    }
}
```

Now, when a user touches the app the gray highlight will overlay my custom view, but not the `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`. 
To fix this, I tried adding `stripeView` above `textLabel` or `selectedBackgroundView`. That didn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are adding should be child of the 'custom view' in order to be highlighted as well, can you check if both textLabel and detailTextLabel are childs?

Comment: So I added `stripeView` to the `contentView` now, because that's where iOS adds the default `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` as well. But it still disappears.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, the view does not disappear. `UITableViewCell` just sets the `backgroundColor` property of every `UIView` in the cell.

Adding the code below, did the trick.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let color = stripeView.backgroundColor
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        stripeView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let color = stripeView.backgroundColor
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    if highlighted {
        stripeView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```